# How to place Dropdown item to be fixed with input element(v-select) on veutify popup modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Started with Vuejs before a week, Iam using vuetify(requirement).

Here is the example provided by `vuetifyjs` for popup modal 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#form

use codepen in above link here to recreate the issue.

[image]

My problem is, after opening pop modal, click(just open) drop-down select without selecting any element or item  when I try scrolling. The Drop down Elements too scrolls along with scroll even.

How can we stop this behavior ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to face this issue today and saw this question without an answer.SO I wanted to post the solution that i found as an answer so that it might help someone in the future.I have solved this issue by adding `attach` prop to

EX:

```
 <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
            <v-autocomplete
              prepend-icon="add_shopping_cart"
              :disabled="isView"
              v-model="answer"
              attach
              :items="answers"
              label="Stackoverflow"
            >
        </v-list-item-content>
 </v-list-item>
```